# how do i initialize private variables in another constructor with parameters that are different

Tags: java, constructor

I have a code that has this set of variables that are initialized inside one constructor, but I need to initialize those variables inside another constructor that doesn't have those parameters in the previous one
this is what the code looks like

```
public class BigCity {

private char[][] grid;
private int numBoxes;
private int numCheese;
private int[][] cheesePos;

private int countMove;
private int countCrumb;
private boolean stillLoose;
public BigCity(int rows, int cols ,int numBoxes, int numCheese, int[][] cheesePositions){
    //initializing the grid
    grid = new char[rows][cols];
    this.numBoxes= numBoxes;

    cheesePos= cheesePositions;
    //initializing the cheese Positions (they are coordinates so columns are never more than two)
    cheesePositions= new int[numCheese][2];
    countMove =0;
    countCrumb=0;
    this.numCheese= numCheese;
    //calling fillGrid method
    fillGrid();
}
//test phase 2
public BigCity(String fileName) {
    // this();
}
```

Comment: You can initialize in the second constructor with default values, but defaults can be set in the declarations (often a good idea).  If you don't want to use defaults, then you have to communicate the values some how.  If you don't want to use defaults, you should clarify your question.

Comment: Look into the Initializer block - essentially common code for all constructors of class - executed prior to each individual constructor, and so each constructor then performs custom initialization.  Syntactically it is a bare `{...}` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html